# What are the new coordinates of P after rotation?

Tags: rotations

Let $P=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and you want to rotate around the $x_1$ axis by $\theta$, what are the new $P'= (x_1',x_2',...,x_n')$ coordinates?
In 2D and 3D it's easy, because we can write up the matrix for rotating and just take the matrix product.

Comment: Shouldn' you rotate around an $n-2$ dimensional hyperplane rather than an axis?

Comment: Given's rotation is what you're looking for

Comment: yes, Givens rotation looks like what I need, David's matrix in his answer is correct if you substitute $n-1,n$ into $G(i,j,theta)$ (except for the minus sign is swapped, but it gives the same result I think).

Comment: You can only rotate about an axis in an odd-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &... & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 &&&            ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 & -\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

is the associated matrix for the linear transformation that rotates the $x_{n-1}, x_n$ plane an angle $\theta$ counterclockwise. Rotation of other planes would have the same Jordan canonical form, although the matrix may appear different

Comment: But this is rotation about the origin. OP is asking about an axis which is basically rotation around a line.

Comment: Rotations occur in planes!

Comment: If I reduce your matrix for 2d plane by considering the lower right 4 elements, then it'd be rotation about the origin. If it is XY plane, rotating about X-axis would lead to the point being shifted into XYZ plane, but the matrrix above wouldn't compute for the z-coordinate.

Comment: @YourIDE I think I haven't understood you. Why doesn't this compute one of the coordinates? You canno make rotations around an axis in 2D space